# Firebase dynamic link flagged as suspicious in gmail

Tags: firebase, gmail, firebase-dynamic-links

**Some Background**

- We have an app which requires users registration
- When a user registers, we send a confirmation email
- The email contains a Firebase Dynamic Link to a web page and is caught by the app if it's installed
- Since the final link contains a unique confirmation token, we generate a dynamic link each time using the Firebase dynamic link REST API
- The generated dynamic link is something like this: https://{domain}.app.goo.gl/{randomChars}
- The final link points to our domain, which is using HTTPS

**The Problem**

- When I try to open that link in Gmail (both desktop and android), a pop-up appears that says:

> Suspicious link
>
> This link has been flagged as suspicious. Are you sure you want to proceed to {domain}.app.goo.gl?

**Notes**

- It's weird that the top-level domain is from Google, and it's flagged as suspicious
- The email contains other links, e.g. to the home page, youtube, instagram and facebook, and those open without any issue (all of them are HTTPS)
- We're using Rackspace/Mailgun to send emails

Any insights will be really useful.

Edit:

I checked both domains ({domain}.app.goo.gl and ours) in [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx) and no blacklist was found.

Comment: Could you share the specific URL you were seeing flagged? (If not here, please file a firebase support troubleshooting ticket and reference this stack overflow thread)

Comment: Right now the problem automagically disappeared, I'll follow up if it happens again.

Comment: this has happened to me today, any solutions?

Comment: @GeekGuy Back then, before the issue disappeared, I was about to follow Ian's suggestion and submit a support ticket [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/)

Comment: this is happening to me as well, is anybody has come up with a solution please share.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic links now use `page.link` instead of `app.goo.gl`. The latter url has been deprecated.
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually

Comment: Im seeing this behaviour with the page.link links as well

Comment: I tested it yesterday, and it didn't mark suspicious for `page.link`. Can you try again?

Comment: @f.khantsis Still facing the issue with page.link